# Clear Eclipse's Internal Web Browser

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging

I'm working at a huge php project, it have many js, and I want to know how to clear the internal web browser cache, because when I'm debugging it, the internal web browser loads a cached version of js files. I didn't try rebuild the entire project because is big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also not an exact answer to the question but some thing relevant to it.
Still now I don't find a simple option (I use Eclipse Indigo) on the "Windows--Preference--General--Web Browser" to clear the internal browser Cache !! - It shows that most of the users are not using the eclipse internal browser.

To clean away the accumulated URL you can remove the entry "*value*" **internalWebBrowserHistory** from the file located in

```
yourworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.browser.prefs
```

I can see a plugin called Advanced Browser on eclipse market-place.. - But not sure it gives any cache clearing facility - it just talks about multiple tab - Need to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I had the same problem and solved it by using an external browser: With Eclipse Indigo and Firefox it worked out of the box even when debugging php. Select Eclipse Settings -> General -> Web Browser -> Use external web browser and select/add firefox.
It seems in Firefox you simply need to refresh the site to get a current version of your javascript code, plus you can use Firebug

Comment: As soon as I click on that Web Browser entry, eclipse (June SR2) crashes.

Answer (score 0):

That file contains:

```
    browsers=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8"?>\n<web-browsers current\="0">\n<system/>\n<external location\="/usr/bin/firefox" name\="Firefox"/>\n</web-browsers>
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

Are the newlines supposed to be escaped like that?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the cache depends on whether Eclipse uses xulrunner or libwebkit for the internal web browser.

For xulrunner, the location of the cache is platform specific:

- On Windows, it is usually in the `Mozilla/eclipse/Cache` directory under the user's home directory or the `Application Data` directory under the user's profile.
- On Linux and Mac, the browser cache is in the `~/.mozilla/eclipse/Cache` directory.

Deleting files from the cache might be sufficient, but if in doubt, you may need to restart the internal web browser and/or Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Internal Browser Output Page
2. Mouse: Right-click and Select Refresh