# JSP file output not updating after changes [Eclipse Internal Web Browser issue]

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Let me start off by saying that I'm completely new to JSP and servlets. I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat 7. I tried the answer given on this question: [JSP page is not getting refreshed after updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036236/jsp-page-is-not-getting-refreshed-after-updating), but it still doesn't update.

Here is my jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Hello world</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%="Hello World JSP"%>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this, the appropriate "Hello World JSP" is output. However if I change the string and run it again, the same old output is displayed. I have to restart Eclipse in order to have the output change, so I'm assuming eclipse is caching the compiled page. Any ideas?

***EDIT:*** The problem has been narrowed down to the Browser cache. The problem only occurs when I use Eclipse's "Internal Web Browser" (Doesn't matter which browser I link that to in preferences). When I run it externally, (through either IE or Firefox), the changes are made.

I'd still like to know however how I can make it so that it updates even using "Internal Web Browser", since it's more convenient.

Comment: Are you deploying from within eclipse? If so, do you see if the tomcat server status changes to "Publishing..." and then back to "Syncrhonized" after you save your change?

Comment: @RobertoLinares sorry deleted my old comment. Yes through Eclipse, and when I save, it does change to "republish" and then back to "synchronized"

Comment: Then maybe the browser is the one who is caching the page and not refreshing the changes in the server. Can you clear your browser cache and check again?

Comment: Hmmm that indeed worked. For some reason though Eclipse uses Internet Explorer (instead of firefox) as the default browser. While I don't mind that, how do I fix this long term through Eclipse? I don't want to have to open internet explorer and delete the cache every time. FYI, right now in Window->Web Browser, "Internal Web Browser" is selected

Comment: A temporary fix was that I changed the Web Browser to firefox. Now the updates are being made, but I would still like to know how to do it within Eclipse's internal browser, since it's more convenient

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that on Internet Explorer but in Firefox's advanced options you can limit the cache to 0MB to make it never use cache when loading pages.Chrome settings has a similar option to avoid saving cache from pages.

Comment: Actually tell the browser how to behave http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/ ?

Comment: @RobertoLinares check question edit

Comment: I added an answer with the instructions to clear the cache in Firefox and Chrome. I also added a link to another StackOverflow question in which they answered how to clear the cache automatically in Eclipse's internal web browser. Also consider @nitind's comment on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the broswer is the one caching your page contents even though Tomcat republishes.

Clear your browser's cache to see if this helps.

Also, you can put your browser in a cache-less mode in their options:

**Firefox:**
Go to Tools menu -> Options -> Advanced tab -> Network subTab and set the value to 0 in the 'Limit cache to #MB of space' field after checking the 'Ignore automatic cache administration' field.

**Chrome:** 
In the Chrome configuration page, go to the Privacy section and click on the 'Content settings' button. In the appearing dialog change the selected option on the Cookies section to any other option that suits your needs.

**Eclipse's Internal Web Browser:**
Check [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759654/clear-eclipses-internal-web-browser) to see how to do it.

Comment: It's not the browser's fault though. When I have it run directly into either IE or Firefox, the changes are made. It's only when I use Eclipse's "Internal Web Browser" (either with Firefox or IE), that the changes aren't made. As for the accepted answer for that question, I don't want to have to delete that file every single time I run, there has to be a way to automatically have eclipse update the changes as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just DELETE your old SERVER(local server like 'Tomcat'). And then again create NEW SERVER.

Comment: That kind of worked for me. I had an issue with local server. But when I have uploaded project on test server, it works perfectly. Don't know what's the reason behind that.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this thread. In order to solve this issue, you may need to open up the source code file relating to your JSP page. Make some miniscule change (for instance, add a space, and then remove it) and SAVE the page. Refresh the webpage that you are running locally. The change should be there.